# Displaying the 'blue location pin' when map's coordinates change

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

Is there a way to manually update the current location on MKMapView and have the 'blue marker pin' displayed to indicate the new spot?

(I'm doing all this with inside the simulator because I don't have my app certificate yet.)

My MKMapView instance is configured with 'showsUserLocation' as YES and when the map is initially shown, I see the 'blue marker pin' (based in Cupertino). When the user taps the 'locate me' button, I do a startUpdatingLocation with an instance of the CLLocationManager.

When I receive the new location update, I'd like to adjust the 'blue pin' on the map but setting the center coordinate on the map doesn't seem to do it?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

       [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

Because the simulator doesn't have GPS functionality, I am manually sending the new location information to make the delegate call to `'locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation'`.

How can I get the blue pin to update on the map with the specified coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't have any luck trying to manually change the device's location from within your app, but you can change the simulated location in the iOS Simulator: From the simulator's Debug menu, select "Location", and then either choose one of Apple's provided locations or enter a coordinate.